# Getting "Query does not returns results" SQL exception

Tags: java, eclipse

I was trying to make a register program in Java in Eclipse.
But i got an error :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Query does not return results
```

You can see my following code :

```
Login.addnewuser(lblname.getText(), lblusername.getText(), lblpseudo.getText(), passwordField.getText(), rankchoice.getSelectedItem());
```

of :

```
    public static void addnewuser(String Name, String Username, String Pseudo, String Password, String Rank) {

    String query = ("INSERT INTO UsersInfos (Name, Username, Pseudo, Password, Rank) " + "VALUES ('"  + Name +  "' , '"  + Username +  "' , '"  + Pseudo +  "' , '"  + Password +  "' , '"  + Rank +  "')");

    connection = SqliteConnection.dbConnector();

    try {

        PreparedStatement name2 = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        name2.executeQuery();

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Can someone help me please ? Thanks :) !

Comment: Beware that your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection)

Answer (score 28):

For `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` use the `executeUpdate()` method and for `SELECT` use the `executeQuery()` method which returns the `ResultSet`.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse, i'm going to try it :) !